# Convert URL to Base64 amscript

Tags: marketing-cloud

An external system generates the qr codes. On marketing cloud we have to retrieve the qr code, then url, after that i should encode it in base64 and show it as an image in a template.

this is the code i am using:

```
%%[

var @getRequest
set @getRequest = TreatAsContent(HTTPGet("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300%C3%97300&data=https://sfmarketing.cloud/"))
set @enc = Base64Encode(@getRequest)

]%%
%%=v(@enc)=%%

<img src="%%=v(@enc)=%%">
```

from what I understand, it does not directly convert ulr to the correct base64 for me because if I try to do it in https://base64.guru/converter/encode/url

Comment: Please provide as many details as possible. E.g. an URL is a text; therefore I don't understand what you mean by "it recognizes it as text instead of URL". Please show, what you've tried. What does "oppre" mean anyway? What do you mean by "it would be a QR code"? You mean, you finally want to render it on your own website as an image with a QR code?

Comment: Hi felix, I have edited the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```ampscript
%%[
VAR @img
SET @img = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300%C3%97300&data=https://sfmarketing.cloud/'
SET @EncodedImg = Base64Encode(@img)
]%%

<br><br><strong>QR Image = </strong><img src='%%=v(@img)=%%'/>
<br><br><strong>QR URL = </strong>%%=v(@img)=%%
<br><br><strong>QR Base64Ecoded = </strong>%%=v(@EncodedImg)=%%
```

> Output
> [image]

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for your answer, but the problem is that when I retrieve a url from a site that generates QR CODE, the answer is an encrypted code and I would like to convert this response to base64 and show the photo directly with base64, so in your case you should print var "QR BASE64Encoded"

Comment: Sorry, the requirement seems to be unclear... it would help me/community to provide best solution, if you could give an Example of what the data would look like when you receive and how you want to display it.